# Laplace's method to determine orbits

Tags: homework-and-exercises, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

I am trying to do the second problem by Laplace's method, it is in spanish but the only thing that matters are the asteroid's observations and the coordinates of Earth

https://freeshell.de/~rgh/arch/mec-unsj-prac-3.pdf

I have two questions:

-Do I need to change sign of Earth coordinates to start Laplace's method? (I think you need Sun's geocentric coordinates).

-I get $$r_2=[1.074622924, .9208669980, -.6249914634]$$ and $$r_2'=[0.003378740005, 0.01675721626, -6.979634229\cdot 10^{-7}]$$
next step is suposed to be changing from heliocentric equatorial coordinates to heliocentric ecliptic coordinates, I can't find the right way to do this.